# Random image with caption

Tags: php, css, random

I have a series of images - image1 to image12. I use PHP to randomly generate the number, resulting in a random image once the page loads.

```
url('img/home/hero-img/hero-img-<?php echo rand(1, 12) ?>.jpg')
```

Each image has a caption like "This is a sunflower".

I am trying to say that if the random number is x then the caption generated should refer to x

Is it a better idea to use a 2D array to store captions and images? That way when an image is selected the caption should be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php may do the trick.

```
$r = rand(1, 2);
if($r == 1) {
// stuff here
}elseif($r == 2) {
// stuff here
}
```

Comment: This is potentially a great solution.